# could't Sign-In Google-play-Services in Genymotion 4.1.1 Emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, google-play, google-play-services

- I m new to android, i have problem in google play services
- I was install **Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip** and
  **gapps-jb-20121011-signed.zip**
- After installation i successfully get google play store in my
  emulator but my emulator browser successfully login gmail.
- after i tried to login in google play services. i clear all data and
  reset but no use .
- can any one please help me.. how to login in google play store ?

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting you Emulator. After you have successfully logged in to gmail, you'll have now other Google Apps like Gmail and Play Store. It will take at least 10-15 minutes to sync and automatically upgrade all the components. Once upgraded, you can now go to Play Store and browse all the apps.

You can follow this [guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952) and [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jbu8WT-naW4).